# Use string items from the list as a variable

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a several lists with items inside:

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
b = [5,6,7,8]
c = [9,10,11,12]
```

Also I have another list with names of lists saved as strings:

```
names = ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

I want to print items from those lists (a,b,c) using name from list names in a loop (smt. like this):

```
for i in names:
    print(i)
```

And the output will be:

```
'a'
'b'
'c'
```

But I want to get:

```
[1,2,3,4]
[5,6,7,8]
[9,10,11,12]
```

I need to convert strings to variables in a loop somehow.

Comment: Please add the general [tag:python] tag to your question.

Comment: You are constructing your list `names` with `strings` and not `lists`

Answer (score -2, accepted):

try below code:

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
b = [5,6,7,8]
c = [9,10,11,12]
names = ['a', 'b', 'c']
for i in names:
    locals()[i]
```

Comment: Thank you. It works

Comment: There's a notable difference between "it works" and "you should actually do this". See [Why is using `eval` bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/why-is-using-eval-a-bad-practice).

Comment: Please don't use `eval`, especially not when there are safer alternatives like `locals()` (or a dict). Newbies reading `eval` answers get the impression that it's ok and safe and normal to use eval, none of which is  true.

Comment: ok, thank you. Will read why eval is a bad practice.

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made and the drawbacks of this approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can create dict of list with 'a','b','c' as keys as follows

```
d = {}
d['a'] = [1,2,3,4]
d['b'] = [5,6,7,8]
d['c'] = [9,10,11,12]

names = ['a', 'b', 'c']
for i in names:
    print(d[i])
```